# Excel VBA - Find 0

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stuck with what is probably a stupid question.  "How to find a cell where the formula returns an answer of 0 (zero)
Column A contains x rows of formula adding each row Column B to D
=`SUM(B4:D4)`
Im trying to delete all rows where is finds this value.

```
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Find(What:="0", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=True).Activate
strDelRow = Activecell.Row
Rows("" & StrDelRow &":" & StrDelRow).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

...but - it can find the zeros as they are in a formula?
Anyone to possibly help?

Many thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can find formulas returning zero.

Looks like you are selecting the entire column A and looking for zeros,
try change the code as follows

```
Range("A1").Select 'Start at the top

Range("A:A").Find(What:="0", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, tried this but couldn't get it to find the data - there is a reply below which did the job - But thanks a stack for the help!

Comment: no problem, just curious as to what worksheet.calculationmode is set to? perhaps setting it to automatic if it is not set to automatic already may help.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim N As Long, NN As Long
    NN = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For N = NN To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(N, 1).Value = 0 Then
            Cells(N, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 This works for OP's purposes but the `.Find` method is more efficient especially in a large set of data where there may only be a few zero-values to delete.

Comment: Thanks chaps, the first suggestion above didn't find the value, but your code above did!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste special values into another column and then use that for your delete code